# Bundle install failed getting error occurred while installing unf_ext (0.0.6)

Tags: ruby, bundler

I have tried running `bundle install` on my Mac but keep getting the following message:

> `An error occurred while installing unf_ext (0.0.6), and Bundler cannot continue.`
>   Make sure that `gem install unf_ext -v '0.0.6'` succeeds before bundling.

But when I install *unf_ext(0.0.6)* I get an error message:

```
ERROR:  Error installing unf_ext:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

make install failed, exit code 2.
```

Any help would be appreciated,

Thank you.

Comment: Is XCode installed on your system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
brew install coreutils
```

installed the missing gmkdir

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue on red hat and fixed it by installing gcc-c++

`yum install gcc-c++`